# Как задать цвет заголовку?

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

Подскажите, какой контейнер или атрибут тега задает цвет заголовку?

Comment: Для этого еще в прошлом веке `css` придумали...  Какой тебе контейнер или атрибут требуется?)))

Comment: Люди учатся, все нормально, мы же тоже такими были когда-то и задавали разные подобные вопросы.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Или ещё проще:

```html
<h1 style="color: red">Hello, world!</h1>
```

Чтобы задать цвет - [`color`](http://htmlbook.ru/css/color).

Answer (score 7):

Как вариант:

```css
.color {
color: red;
background-color: #f5f5f5;
}
```

```html
<h1 class="color">Сегодня воскресенье, сегодня выходной</h1>
```

Ознакомьтесь, каким образом [определяется цвет текста элемента](https://webref.ru/css/color), а также [цвет фона элемента](https://webref.ru/css/background-color).

Обратите внимание на ответ @entithat, на такой способ внесения стилей, это один из способов, он тоже верный. Также можно внести изменения в стили с помощью JavaScript.

Answer (score 4):

```css
html,body{
width:100%;
height:100%;
}
div{
background:red;
width:100px;
height:30px;
}
/*а это на будущее))))  есть теги которым стили не подвласты*/
br{
width:100px;
height:100px;
background:green;
}
```

```html
<!--вот стили для данного тега прописаны в CSS-->
<div>div1</div>
<br/>
<!--вот стили для данного тега прописаны в CSS-->
<div>div2</div>
<br/>
<!--вот стили для данного тега прописаны на пряму  в HTML атрибутом style-->
<div style="background:yellow">div3</div>

<br/>
<!--вот стили для данного тега  можно прописать с помощью JS-->
<!--JS -  'это JavaScript  не путать c JAVA абсолютно два разных языка-->
<div class="div">div4</div>
<script>
document.getElementsByClassName('div')[0].style.background = 'gray';
</script>
```

Answer (score 4):

Если вам зачем-то нужен именно *атрибут или контейнер* (обозреватель древний или движок оформления не поддерживает CSS), можете воспользоваться тегом `<font>`. Однако:

- сейчас принято разделять структуру документа и его оформление, поэтому настоятельно рекомендуется перейти на стили при первой же возможности (как указано в других ответах),
- новые стандарты (HTML5 и будущие) не поддерживают теги, подобные `<font>`. Даже  HTML4 поддерживает этот тег только в переходной версии (из-за чего в примере ниже пришлось явно прописать необходимый doctype).

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" 
  "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
  <head><title></title></head> <!-- Тег <title> обязателен -->
  <body>
    <h1><font color="maroon">Hello, World!</font></h1>
  </body>
</html>
```

К слову, `<font>` позволяет задать цвет не только заголовку, но вообще любому фрагменту текста. Однако он должен быть размещён внутри блочного тега (`<hN>`, `<p>` и т. д.). То есть комбинация `<h1><font>` корректна, а `<font><h1>`  — уже нет (тег заголовка автоматически закроет предшествующий тег).

Comment: Простейший вопрос... Казалось бы ни о чем.... Но сколько вариантов ответа нашлось...))))